# .text in memory being overwritten during execution

Tags: assembly, process, linux-kernel, gdb, portable-executable

I've been working on a simple PE process loader for Linux. I think I've gotten the basics down; much of the code I use comes from `binfmt_elf.c` and `binfmt_aout.c`. My test executable is about is simple as possible (FASM format):

```
format PE GUI 4.0
entry main

section '.text' code readable executable
main:
    mov eax, 4
    add eax, 5
    ret
```

This program (`math1`) is compiled 32-bit, and the VM I'm running in (Xubuntu 12.04) is also 32-bit. I compiled the loader as a kernel module and installed it with `insmod`. The loader appears to work so far, and I've checked for error codes at every possible step. All it does is `mmap` the code section at the start address `0x401000` and call `start_thread()` with that address. If I type something like `./math1.exe` at the command line, my loader is indeed invoked. So, if all goes according to plan, I should get the return value `9` every time.  Instead of executing, however, `math1` segfaults every time, so I opened it up in `gdb` to see what was happening.

Before execution, everything looks normal. If I dump at the start address, I see exactly what I should (I can confirm that this is the machine code for the above program):

```
(gdb) x/9xb 0x401000
0x401000:   0xb8    0x04    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x83    0xc0    0x05
0x401008:   0xc3
(gdb) run
Starting program: /media/sf_Sandbox/math1.exe 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00401002 in ?? ()
```

After the segfault, dumping at the same address, the memory has totally changed, and, from the register dump, it doesn't appear that the first instruction is ever executed:

```
(gdb) x/9xb 0x401000
0x401000:   0x4d    0x5a    0x80    0x00    0x01    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x401008:   0x04
(gdb) info all-registers
eax            0x0  0
ecx            0x81394e8    135501032
edx            0x64656d2f   1684368687
ebx            0x8139548    135501128
esp            0xbfffe5a0   0xbfffe5a0
ebp            0xffffffff   0xffffffff
esi            0x81394e8    135501032
edi            0x2f7ff4 3112948
eip            0x401002 0x401002
eflags         0x210296 [ PF AF SF IF RF ID ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
...more registers...
```

I want to know what would make something like this happen, and what I might be able to do to fix it. I'm suspecting that the code I use to set up the stack frame might be a little... off, but I'm not sure how to tell if that's what's causing this. I know this is a really specific question, but I'm hoping someone can give me some advice.

Comment: Does the mmap:ed memory get execution permissions?

Comment: @JensBjörnhager It's being mapped with protections `PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC` and flags `MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED | MAP_DENYWRITE`. That's the same way the ELF loader does it, as far as I can tell.

Comment: `4d 5a ...` looks suspiciously like an MS-DOS header. Are you sure you didn't accidentally map that in somehow?

Comment: @atomicinf I think you're right. From the hex dump of the executable, that is exactly what's happened. I'm kind of fighting with `mmap` over page alignments, and one of the addresses got messed up, so it's mapping the file at offset `0x0` instead of offset `0x200`. Good catch! Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to make the addresses work so that it's mapped correctly. It's strange that the correct code is there in memory... I wonder how it got there?

Comment: I fixed the memory address problem from previously (instead of `mmap`-ing the file, I had to do an anonymous `mmap`, `kmalloc` some kernel memory, `kernel_read` the section contents, and and `copy_to_user` the code into user space at the correct address). When running in `gdb`, the code is definitely being executed because I get `eax` as `9` when I do `info all-registers` after execution. However, it still segfualts when it gets to `ret`, which makes me suspect that my error now is a stack frame issue. Any recommendations for setting up the stack frame correctly/debugging the issue?

Comment: That probably falls under the domain of a new SO question. Also, you _can_ write and accept an answer to your own question, to prevent it from continuing to be shown as "unanswered". Look into using kgdb too - if it's a stack frame problem then it'll be impossible to debug from userland.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by a faulty page-aligning on my part, and the mysterious hex dump contents were, in fact, the MS-DOS header of the PE file in question. I fixed it by using `kernel_read` and `copy_to_user` instead of `do_mmap` to avoid failure on non-page-aligned sections.